# Distribuir duracion de tiempo SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy en un proyecto en el cual debo realizar algunas mediciones como por ejemplo el uso del tiempo de los empleados, en una base de datos postgresql tengo una tabla con los siguientes datos:

### [image: Muestra de tabla]

Como ven tiene una hora inicio y una hora fin del evento y una duración. Mi problema radica en que cuando el evento comprende mas de un rango de hora por ejemplo (inicia 01:57:45 fin 02:01:15) en donde el evento inicia en el rango de hora de la 1 y finaliza en el rango de hora de las 2, debo poder distribuir la duración del evento en los 2 rangos de hora y generar un registro independiente por cada uno.

Comment: 1: lo recomendable que coloques index en las columnas de mayor concurrencia.
2: en el query que realizas podrias colocarlo

Comment: PieroDev, gracias por tu aporte pero no logro entender para que poner un index, creo que no me explique bien. Tomando el ejemplo anterior inicia 01:57:45 fin 02:01:15 con una duracion de 0:03:30 de los cuales una parte de ese tiempo pertenece al transcurrido entre la hora inicio y las 01:59:59 y el otro entre las 02:00:00 y las 02:01:15, lo que deseo hacer en poder del registro que tengo crear los 2 registros con esta nueva informacion.